# How to install kite in GCP AI Platform (Unified) Notebook?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

When I create a Debian instance in GCP AI Platform (Unified) Notebook to work with Jupyter Lab, I can't install kite (coding assistant).

I follow the steps from [Kite Jupyter Lab Extension](https://github.com/kiteco/jupyterlab-kite#installing-the-kite-extension-for-jupyterlab) and it lets me install the kite engine, but when I do `pip install "jupyterlab-kite>=2.0.2"`, it somehow detects the gcp builtin extensions as outdated, and makes them stop working. After that, tons of things start failing, for instance, trying to do `jupyter lab build` doesn't work, etc.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

AI Platform Notebooks support JupyterLab 1.x, per your link this extension is supported for JupyterLab 2.x and 3.x.
We are working in updating our JupyterLab version.
What you can do is to use custom containers and have a custom JupyterLab version.

https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/custom-container

You will need to use a container with JupyterLab 2.x+. Example: https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/selecting.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually, the version of JupyterLab I'm using is 3.0.10, and I haven't updated it, this is the version it came when I created my instance. I'm using AI Platform (Unified) if that helps. Although I have solved the kite problem (kite was working, I just wasn't noticing it), I still have the problem when running pip, that it detects gcp builtin extensions as outdated for some reason.

Comment: How did you create the Notebook? AI Platform -> Notebooks -> New instance ? What version did you choose. (Latest m65 we still do JLab 1.2.x)

Comment: I could choose between AI Platform and AI Platform unified. I chose unified, went into notebooks, creted an instance with Debian, and I got jupyter 3.0.10

Comment: Hi, I just tried to create a new instance and got jupyterlab 1.2.16. Maybe jupyter got updated somehow while updating sth else. I'll try going back to the right version and come back with results, thank you!

Comment: Problem solved!! It had to do with versions. Than you!